# assign letters to jump forward and backward in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, tcsh, vi-mode

My default shell is `tcsh`.   In my `.cshrc` file. I have `bindkey -v`, so that at the command line,  the letters `b` and `w` jump backwards and forwards a word, respectively.  I'd like to set up bash so that when I switch to that shell, it does the same thing.    I've tried putting `bindkey -v` into `.bashrc` but `bindkey` is not recognized.    Could somebody please explain how to mimic these `tcsh` key bindings in `bash`.    Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `tcsh` shell, `bindkey -v` sets the command line editing mode to "Vi mode" (as opposed to "Emacs mode").

In the `bash` shell, the same effect can be had with `set -o vi`.

Putting the command line editor into "Vi mode" makes it behave a bit as if you were using the Vi editor, where `w` (in "normal mode", after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>) moves to the first character of the next word, `b` moves to the first character of the current or previous word, end `e` moves to the next end-of-word, etc.

You may also switch the Readline library (which the `bash` bash is using for the command line editing) into "Vi mode" by adding the setting `set editing-mode vi` in your `~/.inputrc` file.  Doing this would additionally affect *any other program* using the Readline library for command line editing (such as some interactive mode database clients).

Comment: Thanks to both of you!   This has driven me crazy for a very long time.    For `tcsh` junkies like me, could you perhaps augment your answer to add that if you put the line  `set editing-mode vi` into `~/.inputrc`, then you'll have the property I want by default?